# Jquery ui slider events

Tags: image, jquery-ui, events, slider

I'm trying to do a simple 4 image gallery with a slider to navigate through them.

I am using the code from http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/side-scroll.html . Everything goes well, until I try to make some external handlers for each slide. I have 4 images so I want to make 4 buttons to navigate to each of them. So what I did was :

```
$("#slide_to_1").click(function(e) {
    var c = $( ".scroll-bar" ).slider("value");
    $(".scroll-bar").slider("value", c + 25);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

It controles the slider, but it's not updating the content container. Can anyone point me a way to get through this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post a more complete code example and a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   alert(c);
```

to see if c is filled correctly i think you might have to change to

```
var c = $( ".scroll-bar" ).slider.attr("value");
```

new value will be

```
     $( ".scroll-bar" ).slider.attr("value","newvalue");
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/